# Problem with filestore and ir_attachment Odoo 15

Tags: python, odoo, attachment, odoo-10, odoo-15

Good morning, I would like to post a doubt, I'm migrating my `Odoo 10` to `Odoo 15`, I copied the `filestore` folder to my `Odoo 15`.

The problem is the next one, I have a custom module called `hr.inventario`, this module has 200 PDFs stored, I could import all the PDFs from `ir_attachment` with CSV but not the `datas` field, and I imported all my records from `hr.inventario` with that attachments linked to the records, but I can't access to the content of the PDFs.

Is it possible to generate the data of the PDFs reading the `store_fname`? Any other solution to generate the binary data from the filestore?

I tried exporting the data content with CSV but it gives me an importing error every single time: `"Unknown javascript error token <"`

Comment: How do you migrate the filestore? Because usually you just "copy" it in the new filestore folder of the migrated database.

Comment: I mean, I just copied the folder and then I imported the ir_attachment records with a .csv file to link the store_fname, but when I check the attachment there is no data for download the file I mean

Comment: And there is nothing in the odoo log about permission problems or file not found or whatever?

Comment: No problems, just that the record in ir.attachment is linked with the file in the filestore, but I can't see the file, if you see the record in ir.attachment, the "datas" field is empty and you can't see the file properly, its like "okay, the record in ir.attachment exists, but there isnt file", and I don't know how fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you have copied ok the filestore to the database folder of the new database and the records or inserted ok into ir.attachment table having the name and store_fname already there... you should be seeing everything ok, check the files permissions and double check the paths stored in the database against the filestore/db_name/paths